# How to get specific value from a JSON object

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server table which contains a column `Definition` which has a value of:

```
{ "Key": "comm-health:best-score", "RequiredScore": 70 }
```

Now the value of `RequiredScore` is currently 70 here. It might sometimes be 100 or 150. Now I need the value of `RequiredScore` only from column 70 in the above example.

```
{ "Key":"comm-health:best-score", "RequiredScore": 150 }
```

and 150 in this example.

How can I get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy using the [json_value()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function:

```
select Json_Value(Definition, '$.RequiredScore')
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `JSON_VALUE` to get specific column values.

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE('{"RequiredScore":150}', '$.RequiredScore') AS 'RequiredScore';
```